# Enable verbose debugging to launch.json in Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

How can I enable verbose debugging to launch.vs in Visual Studio Code? At the moment I receive messages, such as `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` without any further information about in which file or on what line the error occurs. This is my launch.vs file:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding to the configurations object:

```
"args": ["--verbose"]
```

This works for Jest